# How to scrape data from google play using php

Tags: php, web-scraping

I have been trying to find a way to **scrape** data from google play but i can't ..
I just want to **scrape** the app name , category , version and googleplay id.

this is the code which is not working :-

```
<?php $data =   file_get_contents('https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.com.com2us.kungfupet.normal2.freefull.google.global.android.common');
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($data);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$query = '//span[starts-with(@itemprop, "gen")]';
foreach ($xpath->query($query) as $node) {
echo $node->value, "\n";
 } ?>
```

How to make a program for the above purposes?

Comment: What is not working? Any errors?

Answer (score 0):

The provided URL is not displaying anything, that might be the first reason.

How ever, I strongly recomend you another HTML parser.
 [nokugiri](https://github.com/olamedia/nokogiri) is the best

Comment: Thanks Emmanuel Orozco but my problem is now solved . Thanks for your contribution